# Série usando recursividade

Tags: python-3.x, recursão

Estou a tentar fazer uma série `x^(n)/n!` mas apesar de parecer simples tenho uma restrição que é: Tem de ser uma função recursiva.
Aquilo que tenho até agora que nem sei se está correto é o seguinte:

```
def serie(x,n):
    if (x and n) < 0:
        return 0
    elif n = 0:
        return 1
    else:
```

Basicamente falta o principal que não estou mesmo a perceber como é que o vou fazer.

Basicamente a minha ideia seria multiplicar o `x` por ele mesmo `n` vezes utilizando talvez um for ou um range(apesar de não saber se posso utilizar o comando range quando estou a trabalhar com recursão) e depois dividir por n fatorial que estava a pensar fazer `n*n-1*n-2 ....`

Até chegar a 0 mas nesta parte nem tenho ideia de como a fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode re-escrever a operação `serie(x, n) = x^n / n!` como

```
x^n   x * x^(n-1)    x    x^(n-1)    x
--- = ----------- = --- * ------- = --- * serie(x, n - 1)
 n!   n * (n-1)!     n     (n-1)!    n
```

Para valores de n >= 1. A última expressão mostra o passo recursivo da sua função.